# Trigger AutoClosable on JVM Shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, architecture, jvm, software-design

**TL;DR**:
Is there a way to find out, that JVM-shutdown is only prevented from the threads started by my code? Is it for example possible to automatically trigger AutoCloseable.close() on Shutdown?

#### Context

I am building a library, that should be used by several customers. This means, besides providing a documentation, I can't enforce certain things.

#### Architecture

(*I try to describe it as abstract as possible and avoid unnecessary details*)

I have a "Manager" object (which is kind of a Factory), that is used to create a "Service" object, that in turn needs some data to work accordingly. Since that data is loaded from some "slow" backend service (which also might change from time to time), I use a separate (Daemon)-Thread that checks for updates and injects new data into that service as soon as available. (This also means that unless the first update, that service is simply in "noop mode". But that's ok.)

Now the "Updater" (which runs in my daemon thread) uses a library that again starts a thread when opening a connection and it's necessary to call "close" to ensure that this secondary thread is stopped - otherwise it is not possible, to shutdown the JVM properly.

As a safety-net I call the close() method inside the finalize() method of my "Manager" (which keeps a reference to all Updater instances). This is not 100% safe, since it's not predictable when GC runs (even more during shutdown!), but it's my only option.

**Update**: [Here is some abstract example code that illustrates the architecture and the according problem](https://pastebin.com/GZuWzf5u)

#### Problem

This architecture causes two possible pitfalls:

1. If the implementation does not keep a reference to the instance of the manager, it will be garbage collected at some point and trough the finalize method the necessary background updates will be stopped.
2. If the implementation keeps an instances of the manager, it must call the close method during the shutdown of the according system, otherwise the JVM can't terminate properly.

So my actual problem is the "potential unreliability" of the developers, which are using that library.

Does anyone have an idea how to build a solution, that could handle both pitfalls?
It would be nice to have some Auto-AutoCloseable ;) that is called during Shutdown (e.g by the DestroyJavaVM Thread or similar).

#### Solutions I tried unsuccessfully

1. Inside the Updater I am closing the "problematic" connection inside a "try-finally" block, but that daemon thread is not interrupted / stopped automatically as well.
2. I registered a `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(...)` that would close all connections, but this shutdown hook is never called since a Shutdown is only initiated when all user-threads are stopped.

### Update: Solved at my implementation, but not the problem

I solved my problem as I found that the third party library (RabbitMQ Client) offers a `setThreadFactory` method that I can use to ensure the spawned Threads are Daemon-Threads.
Good luck for me with my 3rd party library, but the described problem is still possible.

Comment: Your first sentence is misguiding. As far as I understood, you’re talking about the auto-shutdown that happens when no active non-daemon thread exists. Then, your issue is *not* to “enforce the stopping of user threads (daemon=false) *on* JVM termination”, as there is no JVM termination happening, when the user thread have not stopped yet. So the first question is, *what* is supposed to trigger your cleanup? Your manager won’t get garbage collected as long as the threads are alive, but you won’t need this cleanup when they are not alive (as then, the auto shutdown would work).

Comment: You are right, this is exactly the dilemma I have. Actually I want to stop user-threads which are indirectly opened by code running inside a daemon-thread. I'll try to express it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the AutoCloseable resources to be closed so the shutdown is orderly, I guess.

AutoCloseable objects should be used (by your library clients) in a manner that ensures  they are closed when they are no longer needed. In almost all cases, they should be using a try-with-resources block, so they are closed even if an exception is thrown.

You should take advantage of that by requiring your library clients perform a controlled shutdown of each thread when they receive a request to shutdown the program. A thread performs a controlled shutdown by returning from each Runnable.run method, or throwing an exception from each Runnable.run method. I believe this is the only reliable means of closing resources, because it ensures nested resource allocations are reallocated in the correct order. More generally, as a library writer you can not know what other operations your library clients might want to do on shutdown, so you should give them complete control over the shutdown.

You can help them do that by having your library code properly handle InterruptedException and the Thread.interrupted flag.

Comment: I am already doing that. But my daemon threads are never stopped as long as the user-threads are running. See the attached code example. 
I guess you'd advise me to start and stop the connection for every run, but that's not the best usage for the connection (I am using a message queue that waits for data).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess there is no good solution for that problem, but since I found that my 3rd party library gives the possibility to create Daemon-Threads, this is exactly what was necessary to fix it.

Maybe this is also a problem that should be solved on the "human level" by providing a good documentation and ensure a proper usage of AutoCloseable. A good developer should know how to deal with that.

From a technical point of view I found these possible solutions, which are just "safety nets" no one should rely on.

- call "close()" inside the finalize method
- I implemented a service, that can be used to register AutoClosable resources. It runs inside a Daemon-Thread and checks every few seconds, if it finds the JavaDestroyVM Thread and in such a case, closes all registered AutoClosables and stops itself.
  *Disclosure: If a system runs "outside of the main method" (the JavaDestroyVM Thread will run all the time), this is solution won't work.*

**Update**: The RegisterAutoClosable-Service was a very ugly/hacky solution - I deleted it and plan to change the design, to avoid such situations, but finally it's the responsibility of the implementing developer to close opened resources properly.